# How to write metafile (vector image) to clipboard using VB.NET or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I coding the program to create metafile with wmf as extended format. I want to copy that file to paste at MS Word and Excel.

I using as below code to write to clipboard:

Way 1:

`dim st as new system.collections.specialized.stringcollection()`

`st.add("image path")`

=> it can be pasted at MS Word, can not pasted at Excel.

Way 2:

`My.Computer.Clipboard.SetImage(picturebox.Image)`

=> can not paste anywhere

way 3:

`Using bmp As New System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile(current_path1)`

````
            ```    Using pngMs As Stream = New MemoryStream()```

            ```        bmp.Save(pngMs, Imaging.ImageFormat.Wmf)```

            ```        data_img.SetData("wmf", pngMs)```

            ```        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data_img, True)```

            ```  End Using```
            ```End Using```
````

=> get the error such as "ArgumentNullException. parameter:encoder"

Please tell me how to write the metafile (wmf file) to clipboard and paste it at MS Word and Excel.
Thank you so much.

Comment: If you do just `var image = [Some Image from File or elsewhere]; Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, image);`, you can use Paste Special in both Word and Excel to paste a Bitmap object (Paste Special so you can see the ClipBoard format, but you can simply use `Paste`, `CTRL+V`, `SHIFT+INS` etc.).

Comment: See also the [Metafile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.metafile) class.

Comment: thank you so much. It was resolved as my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", entrypoint:="OpenClipboard", SetLastError:=True, exactspelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function OpentClipBoard(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean

    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="EmptyClipboard", SetLastError:=True, exactspelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function EmptyClipBoard() As Boolean

    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetClipboardData", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function SetClipBoardData(ByVal uFormat As Integer, ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="CloseClipboard", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function CloseClipboard() As Boolean

    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetClipboardData", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function GetClipboardData(ByVal uFormat As Integer) As IntPtr()

    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="IsClipboardFormatAvailable", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable(ByVal uFormat As Integer) As Short
    End Function

    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="CopyEnhMetaFileA", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function CopyEnhMetaFile(ByVal hemfSrc As IntPtr, ByVal hNULL As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="DeleteEnhMetaFile", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function DeleteEnhMetaFile(ByVal hemfSrc As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

Public Function func_Put_Metafile_On_Clipboard(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal mf As Metafile) As Boolean
        Dim bResult As New Boolean()
        bResult = False
        Dim hEMF, hEMF2 As IntPtr
        hEMF = mf.GetHenhmetafile()
        If Not hEMF.Equals(New IntPtr(0)) Then
            hEMF2 = CopyEnhMetaFile(hEMF, New IntPtr(0))
            If Not hEMF2.Equals(New IntPtr(0)) Then
                If OpentClipBoard(hWnd) Then
                    If EmptyClipBoard() Then
                        Dim hRes As IntPtr
                        hRes = SetClipBoardData(14, hEMF2)   '14 == CF=ENHMETAFILE
                        bResult = hRes.Equals(hEMF2)
                        CloseClipboard()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            DeleteEnhMetaFile(hEMF)
        End If
        Return bResult
    End Function
```

how to use:
recall that functiion as func_Put_Metafile_On_Clipboard(IntPtr.Zero, metafile_)

Thank all.

Comment: This one is working perfectly ! Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Clipboard.SetImage(New Bitmap("c:\wmf.wmf"))
```

or

```
Clipboard.SetImage(bmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work now on Visual Studio Community 2022

```
Dim mf As Metafile = Metafile.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Using bmp As New Bitmap(mf.Width, mf.Height)
    Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        gr.DrawImage(mf, 0, 0)
    End Using
    bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath & "\tempwmf.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp)
    bmp.Dispose()
End Using
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\tempwmf.bmp")
'result
PictureBox1.Refresh()
```